# How do I accept nested models that are :through has_many with Devise in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, formtastic

I have the following structure and I'm trying to create at least 1 address (with active validation) on the registration of a devise user. The user is being saved fine without validating the address and despite the fact that it is valid, it is being discarded. I've tested and confirmed that I can access :addresses and add them through the console via `user.addresses << Address.new(...)` but not via the form. I'm not sure what's going on here.

Any ideas? Any/all help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_addresses
  has_many :addresses, :through => :user_addresses
  ...
  attr_accessible ..., :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

**models/user_addresses.rb**

```
class UserAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**views/registration/new.html.haml**

```
- resource.addresses.build if resource.addresses.empty?
= semantic_form_for resource, :as=> resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  ...
  = f.inputs :name => "Addresses", :id=> "addresses" do
    = f.semantic_fields_for :addresses do |a|
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try two things:

1. Check your log and see if there's a warning about being unable to mass-assign attributes.
2. Add :addresses_attributes to your attr_accessible

Comment: Ah ha, thanks man! I can't believe I missed that in the logs, ugh.